# XML to HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

So I have a XML file with some data in it. I'm trying to grab it and output it as a HTML table on another page. Found a piece of jQuery but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me fix it or come up with an alternative solution?

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>

<table id="data"></table>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml", 
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {  
            $(xml).find('flight').each(function(){    
                var Col0 = $(this).find('flightid').text();
                var Col1 = $(this).find('departure_aerodrome').text();
                var Col2 = $(this).find('departure_time').text();
                $('<tr></tr>').html('<th>'+Col0+'</th><td>$'+Col1+'</td><td>$'+Col2+'</td>').appendTo('#data');
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**data.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <departures>
    <flight>
      <flightid>1234</flightid>
      <departure_aerodrome>Paris</departure_aerodrome>
      <departure_time>1035</departure_time>
      <remark>Started at 10:36</remark>
    </flight>
    <flight>
      <flightid>2345</flightid>
      <departure_aerodrome>Paris</departure_aerodrome>
      <departure_time>1725</departure_time>
      <remark />
    </flight>
    <flight>
      <flightid>3456</flightid>
      <departure_aerodrome>Paris</departure_aerodrome>
      <departure_time>2045</departure_time>
      <remark />
    </flight>
  </departures>
  <arrivals>
    <flight>
      <flightid>4567</flightid>
      <arrival_aerodrome>Paris</arrival_aerodrome>
      <arrival_time>1013</arrival_time>
      <remark>Landed at 10:18</remark>
    </flight>
    <flight>
      <flightid>5678</flightid>
      <arrival_aerodrome>Paris</arrival_aerodrome>
      <arrival_time>1707</arrival_time>
      <remark />
    </flight>
    <flight>
      <flightid>6789</flightid>
      <arrival_aerodrome>Paris</arrival_aerodrome>
      <arrival_time>2014</arrival_time>
      <remark />
    </flight>
  </arrivals>
</data>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't include jQuery library

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="data"></table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml", 
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {  
            $(xml).find('flight').each(function(){    
                var Col0 = $(this).find('flightid').text();
                var Col1 = $(this).find('departure_aerodrome').text();
                var Col2 = $(this).find('departure_time').text();
                $('<tr></tr>').html('<th>'+Col0+'</th><td>$'+Col1+'</td><td>$'+Col2+'</td>').appendTo('#data');
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Wvc6K/)